# Sample data stored locally with a PhoneGap based app on Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

We had initially planned on developing a native app for Android but PhoneGap is looking like a better option.
One thing we need to have is when the user installs the app,  they need to have local access to a sample of the data in our back end database but have it stored locally.  On the native app we had planned that when the user installed the app,  the installation process would also trigger a retrieval of a chunk of the data in the back end database so that they could make basic usage of the app without relying on an internet connection all the time.
This data will include JPG files and perhaps some audio files.  Will HTML5's local storage address this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: YES

That's what makes phonegap awesome, you may create a database in to store the persisting data details (name & path) 
When you run your application, you will test the connection, if there is no connection you can refer to the local files through your database else if there is connection you may download the new data, save them to the local database and then delete them from the local storage (Sdcard & database).

to find more check the [phonegap's file docs](http://com.codendot.herbal)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what T.Baba has said, yes it is very possible, and I have recently built a webapp with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile that does just that.

I used localStorage to contain all the data, and in particular [localstoragedb](http://nadh.in/code/localstoragedb/). I haven't stored any images and/or audio files in localStorage and wouldn't recommend it anyway as most devices will limit the space to 5MB, but PhoneGap does give you access to APIs which will allow you to save files on the user's device. You can also of course bundle the files with the app and access them accordingly.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use SQLlite for my local storage. There should be no storage limit issues then.  Does HTML5 local storage use ( or be configurable to use ) SQLlite for the actual persistence?

Comment: localStorage is implemented in different ways, it depends on the browser, some of which do use SQLlite. Regardless of this, localStorage usually has a limit of 5MB (at which point the user might be asked if they want to allow more). You could of course store the data in a file and read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is. Phonegap is best option for that.